# Python lazy evaluation?

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

Suppose I have the following code:

```
def my_func(input_line):

    is_skip_line = self.is_skip_line(input_line)  # parse input line check if skip line

    if is_skip_line:
        # do something...

    # do more ...

    if is_skip_line:
        # do one last thing
```

So we have a check for **is_skip_line** (*if is_skip_line:*) that appears twice. Does it mean that due to lazy evaluation the method **self.is_skip_line(input_line)** will be called twice?

If so, what is the best work around, given that **self.is_skip_line(input_line)** is time consuming? Do I have to "immediately invoke" it, like below?

```
is_skip_line = (lambda x: self.is_skip_line(x))(input_line)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a lazily evaluating statement in Python. The only situation in which Python really lazily evaluates is with generators. `self.is_skip_line(input_line)` will only ever be evaluated once.

Comment: `is_skip_line` is evaluated twice, but `self.is_skip_line(input_line)` is only evaluated once.

Comment: Why do you think wrapping a function call in a lambda, then applying it to an argument, would be any less lazy than simply applying the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misconception here is that this statement is not being immediately invoked:

```
is_skip_line = self.is_skip_line(input_line)
```

...when in fact, it **is**.

The method `self.is_skip_line` will only ever be invoked *once*.  Since you assign it to a variable, you can use that variable as many times as you like in any context you like.

If you're concerned about the performance of it, then you could use [`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to really test the performance of the method it's called in with respect to the method it's calling.